# How to change the visibility of an element inside a PHP echo?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a page that has multiple forms that are hidden then shown when that particular function is selected from a select.  What I need to figure out is how I would keep that particular form shown after the user submits.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('funcDisp').display='block' </script>";
    if($_POST['function'] == 'nameFunc') {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $output = "Hi $fname $lname, welcome to my PHP challenge";
    }
}
```

This is an example of what will happen when the first function is selected, but I cant get the echo with the script tags to work for the life of me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){            
        if($_POST['function'] == 'nameFunc'){
           $fname = $_POST['fname'];
           $lname = $_POST['lname'];
           $output = "Hi $fname $lname, welcome to my PHP challenge";
        }
    }
  ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bebk9hPHP.css">
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contentWrapper">
            <h1 id="header">PHP Sample Project</h1>
            <h3 id = "sText">Form Selection</h3>
            <div class="custom-select">
                <select id="dropdown">
                    <option selected disabled hidden>Select a function</option>
                    <option value="1">Function 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Function 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Function 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Function 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="funcDisplay" id="funcDisp">
                   <form action="bebk9hPHP.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="name" id="fieldOne">
                        <input type="text" name="lname" class="name" id="fieldTwo">
                        <input type="text" name="function" value="nameFunc" id="hidField">

                        <div class="submits">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="clear nsubmit" name="submit">
                            <input type="button" value="Clear" class="clear nclear">
                       </div>
                    </form>
               <?php 
                echo "<script>document.getElementById('funcDisp').display='block';</script>";
                echo "<h2> $output </h2>";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
     <script>
        $("#hidField").hide();
        $(".funcDisplay").hide();
         $("#dropdown").change(function(){
             if($("#dropdown :selected").val() == 1) {
                $(".funcDisplay").show();   
             }               
         }) 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is all of my code.

Comment: Where's the `#funcDisp` form placed? Before or after this code?

Comment: After, but putting the same thing after my form doesn't work as well.

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question

Comment: Ok I did.  Sorry. I also moved the statement in question to the echo below.

Comment: You can try doing $(".funcDisplay").show(); instead of the .display=block statement

Comment: That hasn't worked either, could it possibly be where I'm doing it? I've tried inside the isset but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('funcDisp').display='block' </script>";
}
```

inside your document onload or ready function, wrapped in PHP tags. Lose the `<script></script>` tags from your `echo()` since the onload or ready function would already be set to be javascript.

Doesn't appear you have either an onload or ready function, so create one or the other.

Though not the preferred method, an onload tied to the `<body>` tag might be written as so:

```
<head>
...
<script>
    function onloaders() {
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            ?>
                document.getElementById('funcDisp').display='block';
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="onloaders()">
```

But a jQuery document ready function with the same internals would be the preferred method. Either should work however.